# Why are minimal irreducible closed sets in $A^n$ single points?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* example 1.4.4, he says

> A maximal ideal $m$ of $A = k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ corresponds to a minimal irreducible closed subset of $A^n$, which must be a point ...

I don't understand why must it be a point, namely why are points **closed** in $A^n$? Suppose $p = (a_1,\cdots,a_n)\in A^n$, what's the ideal that $p$ is the common zero of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The given point is cut out by the maximal ideal $(x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n)$. One of the versions of the Nullstellensatz is that all maximal ideals of $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ are of this form. Anyway, the Zariski topology is not Hausdorff but it is, at least, $T_1$.

Comment: The Zariski topology on the *maximal* spectrum is $T_1$, but the Zariski topology on the *prime* spectrum usually isn't $T_1$. Indeed, the maximal spectrum can be recovered from the prime spectrum as the subspace of closed points.

Comment: Yes, good point -- I'm trying to keep to the language of Chapter I. I always worry that a lot of answers here jump right to schemes to explain things to people who are trying, as they probably should, to absorb the theory of varieties first. On a related note, I learned from an exercise in Liu that schemes are at least $T_0$.

Comment: This is in Hartshorne Chapter I, so we're not looking at the prime *or* maximal spectra of a ring, but rather at ordered tuples of elements of $k$.

Comment: The point is in Hartshorne the result of maximal ideal comes from the thing that the minimal closed irreducible subset is a point